# 10GbE copper module for Cisco Nexus 3548 switch

Tags: cisco, switch, transceiver

I have a Cisco Nexus 3548 switch and a bunch of machine that I want to connect to it via 10GbE RJ45 connectivity. 
I am a bit overwhelmed with all the acronyms and sheer volume of technical info on this. 
I know what I want looks like this: [http://www.amazon.com/10Gtek%C2%AE-Compatible-Gigabit-Transceiver-Mini-GBIC/dp/B00U77IJ2M/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1449775858&sr=8-1-spons&keywords=cisco+sfp%2B+rj45&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00U77IJ2M)

But this is only 1GbE.
Is there such a thing for 10GbE?

Comment: This Cisco 10 Gb transceiver modules was updated today. I don't see any UTP. http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/interfaces_modules/transceiver_modules/compatibility/matrix/10GE_Tx_Matrix.html

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to tell you that few fiber optic manufacturers and suppliers update 10G copper transceiver modules. You can choose 10GbE fiber connectivity or 10G SFP+ DAC for connectivity. Then the choice would be much wider. Hope the following link helps you. https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/10gbe-interconnect-solutions-overview-fern-xu?trk=mp-reader-card

Comment: I faced this same problem. My conclusion is that PHY module is big enough to doesn't fit in SFP+ space. So, you'll never see a 10GBaseT SFP+ Module. As @katiesi said, your only option for cupper is DAC (aka twinax) cables.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately 10GBASE-T was more power hungry than 1000BASE-T. As a result of this SFP+ manufacturers were not initially able to offer a 10GBASE-T option. This has left an awkward situation with regards to 10 gigabit interoperability.

However it seems things are starting to change. 10GBASE-T SFP+ transcievers are starting to appear albiet with a 30m distance limitation. Prolabs claim to have a cisco compatible 10GBASE-T SFP+ but their website gives no indication of price.